# An error caused by imread() function in AppDesigner in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, imread, matlab-app-designer

I'm using AppDesigner in MATLAB, and whenever I use imread() function inside a button this error message displays:

```
Error using matlab.ui.control.internal.controller.ComponentController/executeUserCallback (line 335)
Error while evaluating Button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.
```

When I put a breakpoint on imread() line I found the entire error message:

```
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
Bundle#166 start failed: Loading C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin\win64\builtins\matlab_toolbox_iofun_builtins\mwmlxcodereader_builtinimpl.dllfailed with error: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible code sample - create a small code sample with the `imread` function in which the error occurs. Copy the entire `app` class, and paste it to your question.

Comment: it is a single line, `I=imread('a.jgp');` inside `function TestButtonPushed(app, event)`

Comment: `I=imread('a.jgp');` or `I=imread('a.jpg');`?

Comment: Sorry, it is  a typo, it is jpg

Comment: Is it working from the command window (I mean: `>>` `I=imread('a.jpg');`?

Comment: I just discovered that imread doesn't also work outside appdesigner! I've always used matlab and imread and it always worked! I didn't change anything in matlab's files.. please check my post I updated it.

Comment: The error disappeared after I restarted my computer ! :) Thank you